# Using UmbracoMembershipProvider into an ASP.NET MVC Website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, umbraco, membership-provider

I am having problems using UmbracoMembershipProvider into another site.

We have a project that contains an Umbraco website and a ASP.NET MVC 3 website for the main application.

We need to use the UmbracoMembershipProvider in the MVC application because we want to use the same admins in both Umbraco and our custom application.

So we have http://website.com (Umbraco) and http://website.com/app (Custom ASP.NET MVC 3)

I added this in our MVC app web.config:

```
<add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" 
       type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider, umbraco.providers" 
       enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
       enablePasswordReset="false" 
       requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
       defaultMemberTypeAlias="Another Type" 
       passwordFormat="Hashed" />

<add name="UsersMembershipProvider" 
       type="umbraco.providers.UsersMembershipProvider, umbraco.providers" 
       enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
       enablePasswordReset="false" 
       requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
       passwordFormat="Hashed"  />
```

I also added this in the appSettings:

```
<add key="umbracoDbDSN" value="connectionString" />
```

I have the same configuration in the Umbraco web.config

When I call the following method:

```
Membership.Providers["UsersMembershipProvider"].ValidateUser(username, password)
```

My IIS crashes and I get a StackOverflowException.

Did anyone have been able to connect an external application to the UmbracoMembershipService?

Comment: You have some infinite loop in your app that's causing stackoverflow and crashing IIS. Probably not related to the membership, unless maybe you are calling some function that calls UmbracoMembershipProvider, which in turn calls that same function.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace with that exception ? And did you check the event log for more details ?

Comment: Thanks for your help but I made it work. Don't really understand why I was having a StackOverflowException but it works now! I will post my answer shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

In my MVC website, I add to create config folder and copy the umbracoSettings.config file in it.

So my folder tree looks like this:

- MVCApp

  - config/umbracoSettings.config
- Umbraco

  - config/umbracoSettings.config

I don't understand why I was having a stackoverflowexception, but this seems to solve my issue.

Comment: Hi - I managed to get this working in v4 - I'm trying to do the same with a v6 database and I can't get it to work! I can't leave it the way it is as validating users fails for some reason, but trying to do something similar with the UmbracoCms.Core package I get object reference errors when calling ValidateUser ... I don't suppose you have any experience with newer versions of Umbraco?

Comment: I have the same applications like you, but I always get the error null exception when calling the Umbraco API in MVC Application 

Could you help me

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my site working with a blank umbracoSettings.config file..